# How can I type cast uint16 to float in Diab compiler?

Tags: casting

I am going to put a uint16 variable into a float type array with (float) casting.
the Diab compiler V9.9.2 make error for this. what is the problem?

Comment: The latest version of the Diab compiler at this time is 7.0.2. Please post a [mcve] including the source code, the compilation command you are running, its full output, what OS you are using, and any other necessary details,

Comment: what does the error say, please provide a sample code or at least the specific errormessage